# ubuntu-minimal 18:04 how to login via ssh?

Tags: server, ssh, login, ubuntu-minimal

I am trying for the first time ubuntu-miniaml.
I just did a setup, then I seen that sshd service is running.
So i tried from another machine to login via ssh, using the standard user created from setup.

I simply cannot.

Ok, I can access my VM from console, but. .. what am I doing wron? what is the new default method of access using ssh if we cannot use username/password and of course my pc keys is not in the authorized file?

I looked into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
# PubkeyAuthentication Yes 
...
# PasswordAuthentication Yes
...  
ChallengeResponseAuthentication No
...
UsePam Yes
```

What is Pam? I need to have ssh access opened upon creation because I'm using scripts to create new vm.

Normally, I create id, access via ssh using username/password, send my keys, then disable ssh login via password.

But with this distro I cannot access via SSH on a fresh setup. I think I'am doing something wron because this distro is born for cloud.

Comment: Is port 22 open and reachable?  What kind of error are you getting? Details please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file configured as below to ssh with password authentication.

## edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.

1. To enable password authentication, uncomment

   ```
   #PasswordAuthentication yes
   ```
2. To enable root login, uncomment

   ```
   #PermitRootLogin yes
   ```
3. To enable ssh key login, uncomment

   ```
   #PubkeyAuthentication yes
   #AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

---

## Sample config file

```
root@test:~# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.
# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none
# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO
# Authentication:
#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes       #prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none
#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes
# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication yes
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none
# no default banner path
#Banner none
# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server**
```